# Does a full-duplex transceiver allow to use both directions at the same time?

Tags: uart

I would need some help with this family of line drivers: MAX3081 from Analog (https://www.analog.com/en/products/max3081.html).

In particular I don't understand if I can receive and transmit via UART **at the same time** with the MAX3081. I am aware that it is suitable for full duplex but it is not clear if it can perform transmission and reception simultaneously.

Some details: for my application I would need to transmit information from MCU1 to MCU2, most of the time. When a signal fed in MCU2 goes high, I need to transmit this event from MCU2 to MCU1 instantaneously, without enabling/disabling anything. So, basically, I need transmission and reception to be active on both sides at all times.

To sum up:

1. Is MAX3081 capable of doing it?
2. Is this possible using only 1 UART per MCU?

Answer (score 5):

In this transceiver (and in all other full-duplex transceivers), the transmitter and the receiver are completely independent:

[image: MAX3081]

This is confirmed by the function tables being independent:

[image: MAX3081 function table]

Being able to do this is the definition of [full duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)#Full_duplex).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was asking about MAX3081 though

Answer (score 2):

> *Does a full-duplex transceiver allow to use both directions at the
> same time?*

and

> *Is MAX3081 capable of doing it?*

I think this table in the data sheet answers your question: -

[image]

Full-duplex means able to transmit and receive simultaneously (providing that you have separate transmit and receive connections).

> *Is this possible using only 1 UART per MCU?*

Almost certainly yes but, you should check the UART you plan to use.

Comment: Can you please what you mean by "the UART you plan to use"? Would you rather recommend to use 2 UARTs with 2 half duplex?

Comment: Whatever swings your boat; I can't guess what UART you plan to use but, most UARTs are full-duplex so only 1 is necessary at each end @mdir

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I am using the UART from STM32L476ZG (MCU1) and from STM32STM32L4P5CGT6 (MCU2)

Comment: @mdir you need to check that it is full-duplex then.

Comment: Sorry for the very silly question. Checking if it is full-duplex means if it has both the TX and RX line on 2 separate GPIOs? @andyaka

Comment: Correct @mdir but, you should also search in the documentation for the term full duplex. CTRL-F helps you search pdf documents and most other document types.

Comment: Thank you for the help